# How to count the length of integer character in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When I am counting the length of integer value in SQL Server, `Len` function is not counting the '0' at first position.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT LEN(09102020) => returns result of 7 chars

SELECT LEN(19102020) => returns result of 8 chars
```

How can I get the exact number of characters using integer string?

Comment: `09102020` This is a integer literal, not a string. When implicitly converted by the engine, the leading zero is ignored. So use a string literal - do NOT rely on implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with a data type handling characters. Numbers data types are not meant to manage leading zeros.

```sql
select len('09102020')
```